# Magento2 - Translate custom links (name) at main menu

Tags: magento2, menu

How can I translate custom links (name) at my main menu?

e.g

Home (/)  ->  Strona glowna  (/)

About Us (/about-us)      -> O nas  (/o-nas)

Contact (/contact)    ->  Kontakt  (/kontakt)

I add custom posiotion to mainmenu in this code:

E:\xampp7\htdocs\mgnt2\app\design\frontend\TemplateMonster\framework\TemplateMonster_Megamenu\templates\html\topmenu.phtml

```
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- RD Navbar Toggle -->
        <button class="rd-navbar-toggle" data-rd-navbar-toggle=".rd-navbar-nav-wrap"><span></span></button>
        <!-- END RD Navbar Toggle -->
        <div class="rd-navbar-nav-wrap">
            <ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
                <?php echo $_menu;?>
                <li class="level0 nav-1 first last level-top  parent rd-navbar--has-megamenu rd-navbar-submenu">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."o-nas"; ?>"  role="menuitem"> <span><?php echo __("Your Custom Menu")?></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Translate Inline Tool

1.   On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration.

2.To work with a specific store view, set the Store View that is to be updated.

3.   In the panel on the left under Advanced, choose Developer.

4.   Expand  the Translate Inline section.

5. Set Enabled for Storefront to “Yes.”

6. Save Config and flush cache.

7. Open your storefront in a browser, and go to the page that you want to edit.

Comment: Ok I changed link's name. But how can I change content at this site? 
Befor I tried to set for my sites shop's language : e.g Main Website>Main Website Store>English   etc.